# Order of options in Unix sed for editing files in-place

Tags: macos, unix, sed

The man page for `sed` says the following:

```bash
sed [-Ealnru] command [-I extension] [-i extension] [file ...]
```

Based on this, I believe the following should work:

```bash
sed -E '/^A/d' -i '' tmp.txt
```

where `cat tmp.txt` gives:

```
A
B
```

But the output is:

```bash
sed: -i: No such file or directory
sed: : No such file or directory
B
```

And `tmp.txt` has remained unchanged.

For the above command to work, I should instead do the following:

```bash
sed -E -i '' '/^A/d' tmp.txt
```

My question is, why? What I tried first should have worked according to the man page. The order of options was just as described there. Yet it did not work.

I'm on a Mac running macOS 12, which is based on FreeBSD.

Comment: For tools complying with POSIX command-line parsing conventions, options need to come before positional arguments. That means the `-i ''` should come _before_ the `'/^A/d'`.

Comment: (see the "Utility Syntax Guidelines" section of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html, particularly guideline 9)

Comment: The example in the man page is given as `sed -i '' -e 's/foo/bar/g' test.txt` which conflicts with the usage declaration, so perhaps the declaration is simply wrong.

Comment: The [manpage](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed) appears to be inconsistent with the [implementation](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/usr.bin/sed/main.c#n125) which uses getopt(3)

Comment: perhaps amusingly, a [comment](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/usr.bin/sed/POSIX#n134) in the source allows tor absence of command entirely. eg. `ls | sed` (GNU sed synopsis disallows this; busybox synopsis allows it but the implementation doesn't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[POSIX utility syntax guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) specify that options -- including options with option-arguments -- should come before positional arguments. While a GNUish command-line parser will recognize options in later positions so long as there isn't an end-of-options sigil preceding them, this behavior (as you've observed) does not reliably extend to non-GNU implementations.

This means that the documentation showing `-i` coming *after* the expression to run was faulty. Reorder your arguments as follows:

```
sed -E -i '' '/^A/d' tmp.txt
```

Comment: As a verification of what you just said, running `sed -E '/^A/d' -i'' tmp.txt` on Ubuntu, which uses GNU bash, works as expected.